# Making a table of probabilities

Tags: probability, uncertainty

I apologize if this is the wrong board - I couldn't think of somewhere better to put it.

I am making a table, going from higher certainty to lower certainty. It represents the probability that two individuals in a database are in fact the same person.

We have three pieces of data - first name, last name, and postal code.

So a top match, for example, would be one where the new individual and the source individual match 100% on first, last, and PC.
The second match can be one in which the first and last name are identical, but the PC only matches on the Forward Sortation Area (first 3 digits).
Names can be matched on the first 1 to 3 characters.

My question is: how should I construct this table? It seems to me that I should build something like a truth table, with faster-alternating traits being those which impact the confidence the least. Which of these traits seem to impact our confidence the least, or how would I go about determining that?

Comment: This kind of problem indeed is of interest here. To address it, one needs data about actual matches and mismatches. If all you have is the database and no independent information about identity of individuals, then what would there be to distinguish any solution from pure guesswork?

Comment: I guess background rates? Reasonable relative / absolute odds of a typo happening in each category, versus odds of people with similar names / postal codes existing at the same time? I dunno.